# Problem with emit after switchMap angular observable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, switchmap

The problem is: when this.getPost())) return error eg 404 (it's function which return GET), then code `this.loggedChange.emit(false)` is not executed and I don't know why. After this situation I have wrong output of loggedChangedHandler. It's look like inside error, after swtichMap, this.loggedChange has not 'observes'. Before switchMap it has observes so I think that it can be clue, but I don't know why it works like this. If first function return error (this.authLogin - it also retur get), then this.loggedChange.emit works fine.

child component:

```
login(): void {
  this.authLogin(this.email, this.password)
    .pipe(
      tap(() => this.loggedChange.emit(true)),

      switchMap(() => this.getPost())
    )

    .subscribe(
      resp => {
        //some code here
      },
      error => {
        this.loggedChange.emit(false);
      }
    );
}
```

in parent component I have something like this:

```
<login-component (loggedChange)="loggedChangeHandler($event)"></login-component>
```

and in ts

```
loggedIn$ = new BehaviorSubject(false);

loggedChangedHandler(el: boolean): any {
  this.loggedIn$.next(el);
}
```

Comment: What does `getPost` do?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have this behavior because the error occurs within your `this.getPost()` call.

Since you don't have an error handler, the observable tries to proceed despite having raised an error.

You could try to add a `catchError` in your pipe like this:

```
this.authLogin(this.email, this.password)
    .pipe(
      tap(() => this.loggedChange.emit(true)),
      switchMap(() => this.getPost()),
      catchError(error => this.loggedChange.emit(false))
    )
    .subscribe(
      resp => {
        //some code here
      },
      error => {
        this.loggedChange.emit(false);
      }
    );
```